# CarrierWave Uploading Using SimpleForm; Why do "remote_image_url" and "image" save to same database column?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, simple-form

I have a simple_form with an image uploader, which is connected to CarrierWave:

```
<%= simple_form_for @house do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :price  %>
  <%= f.input :town  %>
  <%= f.input :description  %>
  <%= f.input :bedrooms  %>
  <%= f.input :bathrooms  %>
  <%= f.input :url, label: "URL"  %>
  <%= f.input :rating %>
  <%= f.input :remote_image_url %>
  <%= f.file_field :image %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Add House"  %>
<% end %>
```

For some reason the two fields

```
      <%= f.input :remote_image_url %>
      <%= f.file_field :image %>
```

are storing to the exact same column in my database, which is named "image". I don't understand why.

Comment: because that is how carrierwave work either you attached a file from your machine **OR** attach a link from the web and carrierwave would download it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By carrierwave, you can either upload file/picture from your machine directly by `<%= f.file_field :image %>`, or from the link on remote server using helper method 'remote_image_url' . This naming convention `remote_yourimagefield_url` is important, as carrierwave will come to know by this naming structure to grab files from the remote server. As :remote_image_url points to the same column as :image, therefore they are stored in the same column